# ROO looking for Bundles in wrong folder

Tags: spring-roo

I have downloaded Spring roo 2.0.0. First I extracted the bundle in download folder itself. Ran it for testing and then transferred the bundle to different Folder.
I have also added this new folder to System Environment ROO_HOME and PATH.

But when I try to run any command, ROO still tries to look up bundles in Download folder.  Is roo saving that path somewhere? Please help. I have tried to look everywhere for the configuration and have found nothing.

Comment: You may need to re-login when changing the path variable.Can you verify the content of $PATH?

Comment: I had to reinstall roo. Roo was looking for the bundle in a folder were I previously installed.  I was keeping record somewhere. I deleted the whole thing and reinstalled everything from scratch.